# Solarized theme doesn't work in all windows in Intellij Idea after trying out New UI in Intellij 2022.3

Tags: intellij-idea

After upgrading from Intellij 2022.2 to 2022.3 and trying to enable the "New UI":

[image]

then my solarized theme didn't seem to work as before. The "code window", terminal etc uses solarized, but other windows, such as the "project window", doesn't as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

I've tried disabling the "New UI" again, but Solarized still won't be applied to all windows the way it previously used to. I've tried using both "Solarized Theme" (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14920-solarized-theme) and "Solarized Themes 4lex4" (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12784-solarized-themes).

Question: How do I get the solarized theme to work in all windows (preferably with the "New UI" if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

The "Main Changes and Known Issues..." link says only to use the Light and Dark themes with the new UI to avoid issues like this.

> The new Light and Dark color themes have improved contrast and a
> consistent color palette.
>
> Please use only these themes while working with the new UI. Other
> themes might look misaligned and have unexpected colors.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-156/Main-changes-and-known-issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer just as I asked the question ‍♂️ If anyone else have the same problem, you should go to

`Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance`

and select the solarized theme. Then all windows will use solarized.